# Does the merging step of git pull happen to the fetched remote branches not corresponding to the local current branch?

Tags: git

*Version Control with Git* says about the merge step of `git pull`:

> But how did Git know to merge those particular branches? The answer
>   comes from the configuration file:
>
> ```
> [branch "master"]
>         remote = origin
>         merge = refs/heads/master
> ```
>
> Paraphrased, this gives Git two key pieces of information: **When master
>   is the current**, checked out branch, use origin as the default remote
>   from which  to  fetch  updates  during  a  fetch  (or  pull). 
>   Further,  during  the  merge  step  of git pull, use refs/heads/master
>   from the remote as the default branch to merge into this, the master
>   branch.

It is possible that the fetch step of `git pull` may fetch more than one remote branches (because of `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`).

But the merge step only says that merging happens to **the fetched remote branch corresponding to the local current branch**. Does merging also happen to **the other fetched remote branches which don't correspond to the local current branch**?  If yes, when does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake embedded in your question.

> It is possible that the fetch step of git pull may fetch more than one remote branches (because of `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`).

A plain `git fetch` would indeed fetch *all* the remote's branches (`refs/heads/*`).  But `git pull` does not *use* a plain `git fetch`.  It uses a variant in which `git fetch` updates only *one* remote-tracking name (assuming Git versions >= 1.8.4).

That's not actually all that important to the main point of your question for other reasons, but to be really clear, I've added a (very) long description of how `git fetch` operates and how `git pull` uses that.  Meanwhile let's tackle the *second* command that `git pull` runs.  Remember, `git pull` is essentially:

- run `git fetch` (with various options), then
- run a second Git command, typically `git merge` (with various options).

The *first* command collects objects—mainly commits, plus anything necessary to make them complete—from some other Git repository.  After the fetch, your Git has (some of / enough of) their Git's commits, but they are not part of *any* of *your* branches.  You probably want at least some of them to be part of at least some branch, and that's where the second command comes in.

If the second command is `git merge`, your Git runs:

`git merge -m message hash1` [ `hash2 ...` ]

That is, your Git specifies a merge message—of the general form `merge branch 'B' of URL`, for some *B* and *URL*—and one or more, but we hope only one—commit hash IDs.<sup>1</sup>

In any case, *any* `git merge` command affects only the *current* branch.  Any merge:<sup>2</sup>

- errors out (e.g., "not something we can merge", "already up to date"), or
- completes normally, or
- does a fast-forward operation instead of merging, or
- stops in the middle due to a merge conflict or user request (`--no-commit`).

For the normal and fast-forward cases, the result is that the current branch name—the one to which `HEAD` is attached—points to some different commit: a new merge commit for a real merge, or the hash ID given as the target of the merge for the fast-forward case.

So the answer to:

> Does merging also happen to the other fetched remote branches which don't correspond to the local current branch?

is *no*, but the question itself is confused, or at least confus*ing* in its wording: merges happen *to* the current branch only!  Since you can only *check out* local branches, only *local* branches ever get merged-into.  In that sense, merges can only "happen to" local branches.  I'd have to guess at your meaning for the phrase "merging happen(ing) to ... remote branches".  (See the very long "Long" section below for such a guess.)

Note that the `git merge` command takes *as arguments* one or more commit hash IDs.  These other-commit-hash-IDs *may* be specified via remote-tracking names, or as raw hash IDs, or in any other way that Git accepts a hash ID, such as a relative name like `develop~7^2~3` (though I'd never recommend this last expression).  The `git pull` command always uses raw hash IDs, but hides this fact via `git merge`'s `-m` argument.

---

<sup>1</sup>The case where it specifies more than one hash ID is almost 100% due to user error.  This user error is, in my experience, very common, because `git pull` is a poorly-designed command:  Think of it as a multi-bladed Swiss army knife where several blades can never be closed, so that you always cut up your palm every time you use it, unless you hold it *very* delicately.  A multi-hash merge generally results in what Git calls an *octopus merge*, but I don't want to get into all the gory details of that here.  This answer is already way too long.

<sup>2</sup>The `git merge --squash` operation is very similar to `git merge --no-commit`, as `--squash` turns on `--no-commit`.  This forces you to make the final commit yourself.  What's special about `git merge --squash` is that the new commit that Git will make, when you make the commit yourself, *isn't a merge commit after all*, but instead is a normal, single-parent commit.  It's otherwise exactly the same as `git merge --no-commit`.

## Long

Some of the trickiness here is due to the way `git pull` invokes `git fetch`.  To understand that, we have to start by *really, deeply* understanding `git fetch` itself.

#### `git fetch`

The `git fetch` command is complicated, with a lot of this complication being due to the way really-old Git worked.  Ancient, primordial Git did not *have* remote-tracking names: there was no such thing as `origin/master`.  This led to a lot of ugliness, so eventually the Git folks invented remote-tracking names, but for backwards compatibility reasons, they could not just *assume* remote-tracking names.  That's where a lot of the weirdness comes from.

Without worrying about that for the moment, remember that `git fetch` has several phases.  The first phase is the entire conversation for `git ls-remote`.  I encourage people learning Git to run `git ls-remote` at least once, to see what the *other* Git tells *your* Git at the start of any `git fetch`.

Remember too that the syntax for invoking `git fetch` is (simplified):

```
git fetch [<remote> [<refspec1> [<refspec2> ...]]]
```

The *`remote`* typically defaults to `origin` but of course you can be explicit and write out `origin`.  Any *other* arguments *after* `origin` (or some other name) are *refspecs*.  We'll assume for the moment that you are *not* providing any refspecs, so that we don't have to define how they work; and we'll assume that your Git and their Git are using the so-called smart protocols (the dumb ones can waste a lot of time transferring useless data, so let's not go there).  Last, we'll assume a standard `fetch =` line, reading `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Here's actual `git ls-remote` output, trimmed a bit (ok, a *lot*), for the Git repository for Git:

```
ecbdaf0899161c067986e9d9d564586d4b045d62        HEAD
0d0ac3826a3bbb9247e39e12623bbcfdd722f24c        refs/heads/maint
ecbdaf0899161c067986e9d9d564586d4b045d62        refs/heads/master
2a65cea5f9ce26d22baec1ec541c86d41e2e700a        refs/heads/next
855f98be272f19d16564ed44d8e858d8d459d7e5        refs/heads/pu
0596e1ad5143dab167e62bf39387d2b4e06cadb6        refs/heads/todo
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86        refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
3d654be48f65545c4d3e35f5d3bbed5489820930        refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0^{}
[massive snippage]
dcba104ffdcf2f27bc5058d8321e7a6c2fe8f27e        refs/tags/v2.9.5
4d4165b80d6b91a255e2847583bd4df98b5d54e1        refs/tags/v2.9.5^{}
```

As you can read from the rightmost column, their Git told us about the five branches that they have: `maint`, `master`, `next`, `pu`, and `todo`.  (They also gave us a recommended branch to check out, via `HEAD`, and a list of about 20 bajillion tags along with the commits that those tags identify.)

Anyway, the first phase of `git fetch remote` is that your Git calls up some other Git, at some URL—the (presumably long and hard to type) URL is stored as a configuration entry using the shorter, easier, more-meaningful *`remote`* string—and does exactly what `git ls-remote remote` prints out.  That gives your Git a complete list of all of *their* Git's branch and tag names.

Your Git then runs the list through the `fetch =` lines, **if** you have not provided any refspecs.  That gives your Git the list of remote-tracking names, such as `refs/remotes/origin/master`, to create or update.  It also gives a list of commit hash IDs that your Git will *need*.  Remember, any name like `refs/remotes/origin/master` in the name-to-hash-ID database must provide a *valid* hash ID, not just any hash ID.  So for your Git to create or update your `origin/master`, it's going to need to have, locally, the commit whose hash ID is (in this case) `ecbdaf0899161c067986e9d9d564586d4b045d62`.

At this point, your Git will add these required-commit-hash-IDs to the list of commits it needs to ensure are present.  It now enters the "have/want/dontwant" phase of the conversation.

For every commit ID that the sender has and can send, it will say: *I have the commit with hash ID H*.  For every commit that your Git *wants*, your Git will say: *Yes, please send me that commit, and tell me about that commit's parents too.*  If your Git already *has* that commit, though, your Git will say: *No, I don't need that commit after all.*  Then their Git will tell yours the parent hashes and your Git can say yes or no as before.  If your Git wants those parents, their Git tells your Git about the parents' parents, and so on.  Eventually, by following these parent chains backwards, your Git reaches hash IDs that you *do* already have, so your Git says *no* to those; once your Git has refused all the parents, or their Git has run out of parents, the two Gits move on to the actual data transfer.

To accomplish the data transfer, their Git now packages up all the selected commits (if any—maybe you already had all branch-tip commits) and any required sub-objects and sends them, as what is called a *thin pack*.  This is kind of compute-intensive on *their* end; you may see messages about the remote counting and compressing objects.  Meanwhile your Git just passively receives the thin pack data, until this phase is done.  This is usually the slowest part of the conversation, and is where you see the downloading messages with the number of MiB/second or whatever.  Your Git then "fixes" the thin pack, turning it into a normal (thick?) pack.  This is a pretty compute-intensive phase on *your* end, and you may see more messages about checking connectivity and the like, but one way or another, now your Git has all the commits, plus all other objects needed to make those commits complete.

The *conversation* is all done now, so—again, assuming a standard `fetch` line—your Git moves on to updating your remote-tracking branches.  Now that your Git has the necessary commits, your Git replaces the old value of your `refs/remotes/origin/master` and so on with their new values.  Each of these update operations:

- can be a fast-forward, and/or
- can be forced (with the leading `+` sign in the fetch refspecs).

A forced update is one that Git will do, even if the update operation itself is not a fast-forward.  A fast-forward update is any update in which the *new* hash ID leaves the existing hash-ID *reachable* (for a full discussion of reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/)).  So this last phase tries to update each mapped name.  Usually this is forced-if-needed, so that all these updates complete regardless of fast-forward-ness.  Your Git prints:

```
   <oldhash>..<newhash>    master -> master
```

if your Git has updated your `refs/remotes/origin/master` based on their `refs/heads/master` and the update was a fast-forward.  The `<oldhash>` is the abbreviated old hash ID for your `refs/remotes/origin/master` and the `<newhash>` is the abbreviated new hash ID.

Your Git prints:

```
 + <oldhash>...<newhash>   master -> master (forced update)
```

(note the plus sign and the three dots, as well as the parenthetical remark) if the update was *not* a fast forward, but happened anyway.

(Your Git prints nothing, and does not update your remote-tracking name, if the update is not a fast-forward and was not forced.  This never happens in practice, since the standard `fetch =` line has the plus sign.)

#### Now that we know how a plain `git fetch` works, let's look at one with refspecs

First, of course, we need to define *refspec*.  Both `git fetch` and `git push` use them, although they vary a bit in details.

Refspecs are really pretty simple: they're mostly pairs-of-names with a colon in between the two names.  There's an optional plus sign at the front, meaning *force*.  That is, we can write:

```
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

which is a lot like what we see in the `fetch` line.

The thing on the left of the colon (after the plus if any) is the *source*, and the thing on the right is the *destination*.  So this refspec means *use `refs/heads/master` as the source, use `refs/remotes/origin/master` as the destination, and set the force flag*.  We'll grab *their* `master` and make it *our* `origin/master`, and we'll force the update if we have to.

But you don't have to write out a full refspec like this.  For instance, you can leave out the `refs/heads/` (or for tags, the `refs/tags/`).  In this case, Git will *guess* whether you meant a branch name or a tag name by inspecting the contents of your and/or their names.  This is a bit sloppy—if you write `master:master`, for instance, what happens if there's not only a *branch* named `master`, but also a *tag* named `master`?  I don't know the answer—I'd have to test to be sure—but I *think* Git will prefer the tag here, just as it does for most local name lookups.  Still, people do this all the time—leave out the `refs/heads/`, I mean, not make a tag named `master`. :-)

In the end, what this means is that you'll see refspecs like `master:master` a lot.  This is particularly useful with `git push`, and hardly ever useful with `git fetch`: we don't want to overwrite *our* `master`, we want to update our `origin/master` instead.

You can also use a sort of *half*-refspec:

```
master
```

or:

```
:delete
```

What these mean is more complicated—in particular, it's *different* for `git fetch` and for `git push`.  With `git push`, `:delete` is a request to have the other Git *delete* a branch or tag name.  With `git fetch`, omitting the source makes no sense at all.  (Testing shows that Git interprets the missing source as `HEAD`, but I would advise against assuming this—it's not documented anywhere.)

Omitting the *destination*, on the other hand, tells `git fetch` that it *shouldn't update anything locally*.  That is, if you run:

```
git fetch origin master
```

you are telling Git: *Bring over their `master`, and don't touch any of my branch names.*  This is more sensible, since your branch names are *yours*, not theirs to overwrite!  You could, of course, do:

```
git fetch origin master:newbranch
```

which would create a *new* branch in your repository named `newbranch`, matching `origin`'s `master`.  And in fact, this is something people did in the bad old days, before remote-tracking branches existed.  But in modern Git we have remote-tracking names, like `origin/master`.  So we want `git fetch origin master` to update `origin/master`.

(With `git push`, omitting the destination means *use the same name as the source*, so `git push origin master` means `git push origin master:master`.  That's the biggest fetch-vs-push asymmetry.  When you push, you're not using any kind of remote-tracking thingy in the *other* Git.  No, you're using *their Git's branch names* directly!)

Anyway, ever since Git version 1.8.4, your Git will just *automatically update* your `origin/master` when your Git brings over their `master` (assuming a standard `fetch =` line, again).  Prior to that version of Git, though, `git fetch origin master` did in fact fetch their `master` and then ... not update *anything at all*.

**Well, that's a bit of a lie,** because `git fetch` *always*—since time immemorial—*also* creates or appends-to the file `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  This is where `git pull` comes back into the picture, but first, let's finish out this scenario.

#### `git fetch` with no refspecs obeys your `fetch =` setting

If you run `git fetch origin`, or `git fetch` with no arguments at all and Git picks `origin` as the remote, Git will use your `fetch =` settings to decide what to fetch.  The normal setting is "bring over all their branch names, and rename those to remote-tracking names", and that's forced by the standard refspec, with the two asterisks and the leading plus sign.

The other somewhat-less-normal, but not crazy-weird, `fetch` line is the one created by `git clone --single-branch`.  Instead of `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, it reads `+refs/heads/somebranch:refs/remotes/origin/somebranch`.  That's what makes your clone *single branch:* every `fetch` you run, with no arguments, only updates your one remote-tracking name, from that one branch in their Git.  Then there are the weirder `fetch` lines created by `git clone --mirror`, but they don't apply to normal, non-mirror clones, and mirror clones are bare clones, which don't let you do any work, so we'll just ignore them.

In both of these normal cases—a regular clone, or a single-branch clone—your `git fetch` will bring over all, or one, branch, and update all, or one, remote-tracking name.  Then—to maintain backwards compatibility, your Git will update your `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, stuffing into it *all* the names that your Git brought over, and their hash IDs.  Nobody needs to care, because the remote-tracking names have all that stuff.  The `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file contents have no real use at all.

#### `git fetch` with refspecs obeys your refspecs

Suppose, though, you run `git fetch origin master`.  That gives a *refspec*, and your Git will obey it.  Your Git will fetch *only* their `master` branch.  Your Git will then update your `origin/master` automatically, *if* your Git is at least 1.8.4, because that's a sensible thing to do and your `fetch =` line is normal.

In *every* case, though—even on a really ancient Git—your Git will *also* update your `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, and this time, this has a point.  If your Git is ancient, this is the *only* place that remembers what hash ID just got brought over, because your ancient, pre-1.8.4 Git *didn't* update `origin/master`.  If your Git is newer than that, your Git *did* update `origin/master`, but—here's `git pull` again—**maybe this `git fetch origin master` was run by `git pull`.**

#### `git pull` always provides refspecs

As we now know, if you run:

```
git pull
```

(and assuming this does anything useful), your Git will run `git fetch` for you, and then run a second command for you.  If you run `git pull` with *no* arguments, the `git fetch` that `git pull` runs comes from the configuration:

```
$ git config --get-regexp '^branch\.master\.'
branch.master.remote origin
branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

The actual `git fetch` that `git pull` will run is therefore:

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/master
```

The `origin` part comes out of `branch.master.remote` and the refspec is literally just the exact value of `branch.master.merge`.  This configuration goes all the way back to the days when Git did not have remote-tracking names.

This particular `git fetch`, we now know, will contact the other Git at `origin` and bring over their `master` branch's tip commit, due to the `refs/heads/master` part.  That in turn will bring over other master-branch commits as needed.  Our Git may or may not update our own `refs/remotes/origin/master`, depending on our Git vintage, but in all cases, our Git will write, to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, the hash ID of their `master`-branch tip commit.

Having done that, our `git pull` will then *fish this hash ID out of the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file.*  **This** is where the hash ID comes from, when our `git pull` runs `git merge` for us!  Any update to `origin/master` is incidental, as far as `git pull` is concerned.

We can also run:

```
git pull xyz
```

In this case, our Git will use `xyz` as the remote name, but will still run:

```
git pull origin refs/heads/master
```

because `branch.master.merge` is set to `refs/heads/master`.  So this time `git fetch` will call up whatever URL is listed under `xyz`, get *their* `master`, and maybe update our `refs/remotes/xyz/master` depending on our Git vintage.  But once again, our Git will write to `.git/FETCH_HEAD` the actual *hash ID* fetched for their `master`, and our `git pull` will pass this hash ID to `git merge`.

We can run:

```
git pull anyremote foobar
```

and our `git pull` will run:

```
git fetch anyremote foobar
```

which will go through all the fancy matching we describe above to figure out whether to bring over their `refs/heads/foobar` or their `refs/tags/foobar`.  But no matter what else happens, if this `git fetch` works at all, it writes the hash ID for `anyremote`'s `foobar` to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, and then our `git pull` fishes the hash ID out and runs `git merge`.

#### Here's where the terrible tool `git pull` stabs users, over and over again

Given that users have learned to run:

```
git pull origin master
```

they immediately start to think: *Hey, if I can pull master, why can't I pull master and develop both?*  They run:

```
git pull origin master develop
```

**Now, in concept, this is a perfectly reasonable request, but `git pull` doesn't do it.**  Instead, `git pull` runs:

```
git fetch origin master develop
```

The `git fetch` command dutifully calls up `origin`, brings over any commits needed for its `master`, brings over any commits needed for its `develop`, and maybe-updates remote-tracking names, depending as usual on our Git vintage.  Then our `fetch` updates `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, writing into it *both hash IDs*.

Now our `git pull` runs **one and only one** `git merge`:

```
git merge -m $message $hash1 $hash2
```

This produces an *octopus merge* into our current branch.  To get two separate merges, the way the user *wanted*, `git pull` *should* have done:

```
git checkout master && git merge -m $message1 $hash1 &&
git checkout develop && git merge -m $message2 $hash2
```

with the two obvious messages and the two hashes.

This is one of many reasons I recommend that Git newbies *avoid* `git pull`.  It does something very surprising.  Many programmers make this mistake—I did, and multiple colleagues did, back in the early days of Git, more than a decade ago.  The documentation is much better today, so maybe fewer users make this mistake, but it still takes a lot of explaining before this makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Other *local* branches are not affected by `git pull`. (But your branches' corresponding pointers to `origin` *are* updated).

If you switch to a different branch that has also been updated, you can use `git merge` or `git rebase` to update your local branch to the remote branch. `git pull` doesn't really do anything more than `git fetch && git merge` would do (`git rebase` if your `pull.rebase` config value is set to `true`).